# How to extract characters before a pattern

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I need some help on how to extract a specific string of a line.

I have a file with thousands of lines like this:

```
Eukaryota; Alveolata; Ciliophora; Intramacronucleata; Paramecium#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae; Streptophyta; Embryophyta#
Bacteria; Cyanobacteria; Synechococcales; Acaryochloridaceae; Acaryochloris#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae# 
Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria#
```

And I would like to obtain the first and the last item of each line. So the output would be:

```
Eukaryota; Paramecium#
Eukaryota; Embryophyta#
Bacteria; Acaryochloris#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae# 
Bacteria; Alphaproteobacteria#
```

I know how to get the 1st column with

```
awk '{print$1}' fileIn > fileOut
```

but I don't know how to get the last item as it is always in different columns.

I tried adding the # and then just keep XX characters before the # with

```
grep -E -o '.{X,X}PATTERN. fileIn > fileOut
```

where the output looks like:
les; Sulfolobaceae; Sulfolobus#
; Thermoproteaceae; Caldivirga#
les; Haloferacaceae; Haloferax#
 Haloferacaceae; Haloquadratum#
ales; Natrialbaceae; Natrialba#

But then I have to repeat the procedure and remove ; until I'm left only with the final item.

I've search to see if there is any grep or awk option to do that, extract 1st and last column or extract just the characters attached to # but I could not find any that work for me.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: You may use `$NF` to get the last filed in each line, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks $NF is not exactly what I wanted but it works in case I just need the last item. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{print $1,$NF}' file
Eukaryota; Paramecium#
Eukaryota; Embryophyta#
Bacteria; Acaryochloris#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae# 
Bacteria; Alphaproteobacteria#
```

Comment: @vimac see what to do [when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Since the separator in your file is `;`, you may also use `gsub(/;.*;/,";",$0)` to filter out the field between two `;` to get the first and the last field.

```
$ awk '{gsub(/;.*;/,";")}1' fileIn > fileOut
$ cat fileOut
Eukaryota; Paramecium#
Eukaryota; Embryophyta#
Bacteria; Acaryochloris#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae# 
Bacteria; Alphaproteobacteria#
```

Comment: Nice. `sub` is probably enough, though.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @RavinderSingh13. It's better now.

Comment: if you are going to use just sub on whole line, might as well use `sed 's/;.*;/;/'`... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1,$NF}' file

Eukaryota; Paramecium#
Eukaryota; Embryophyta#
Bacteria; Acaryochloris#
Eukaryota; Viridiplantae#
Bacteria; Alphaproteobacteria#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Perl one liner

```
perl -aF';' -ne 'print "$F[0],$F[-1]"' test.txt
```

`-a`    Auto split mode

`-F';'` Setting delimiter as ;

And the splited data stored in `@F` array

`$F[0]` Contain first column (first index)

`$F[-1]` Contain last column (last index)